# Variables that represent variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, notation, terminology

Can we use 'variables' to represent other 'variables' that represent mathematical objects? For example:

If I have a system of equations of $n$ variables $x_1+x_2=x_3$, $x_4+x_5=x_6$ etc

I can say:

For variables $a,b,c$:

$a+b=c$

In this case $a,b,c$ are varying over variables themselves.

Indexed variables sort of work this way as I can express something like:

$x_i+x_{i+1}=x_{i+2}$

for $i$ an element of {$1,4,7...$}

where the symbols $x_i$ can be seen as varying over the values of the variables as $i$ changes.

Is this something that is do-able or are $a,b,c$ themselves simply real-valued variables?

Comment: If the variables $x_i$ over which $a,b,c$ vary are themselves real valued I do not see a reason why $a,b,c$ could be anything else than real-valued variables. Seems you overthink this by far.

Comment: See [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think I need to look into the metalanguage, to understand this.

Comment: The second half of your post is the usual solution if you need something like this in “every-day maths”. Otherwise, you need to “reify” the concept of a variable in some way. In logic, you might introduce them as abstract symbols; in algebra, you have “indeterminates” which are usually elements in some sequence space; in differential geometry, they might be certain functions defined on your manifold.